# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ipaddress' (4) (2003)

Tags: mysql, remote-access

```
$mysql_host    = "myipaddress";
$mysql_user    = "user";
$mysql_pass    = "password";
$mysql_db      = "mydb";   

 $con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db);

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_errno() ." ". mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

I use phpStorm as well and using the same configurations (ipaddress not localhost) it connects to the database (database is on my local system; phpmyadmin).

I am using phpmyadmin locally. I can connect using their interface and local host just fine as well. in PHPStorm I set up a local AND a remote connection. The local using localhost, and the remote using my systems outside-world IP address. I can access the db using both methods inside PhpStorm.

However when I put the above code in a php doc and run it on a remote server to access my local db the same way I have phpstorm doing it, I get the error.

When I try to ping 3306 via telnet (win7) i get gabled text and "Got packets out of order .. Connection to host lost." Again using the same info I can connect using phpstorm. Whats up with this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several things you may want to check.

1. Most probably you firewall is filtering outside connections to port 3306. phpStorm and phpMyAdmin connects fine, cause they are running on the same machine.
2. Check if your MySQL server is actually listening for connection on
   your real IP.  It might listen only on localhost.
3. If you are behind a router, you need to port forward 3306 to your
   actual machine that is running the MySQL server.